# How to connect development studio and wso2 business rules server?

Tags: wso2, esb

Anyone Provide me BusinessRulesServer (Rules) Example ?
How to configure development studio and ESB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following link.

link# http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/05/eclipse-plugin-wso2-business-rules-server/